# Unable to pass the value of variable from one class to the another class in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have made a helper class for `MFMessageComposeViewController` so instead of view controller I have made my class with MFMessageComposeViewController as base class.

Now I am trying to present this Controller from my another controller named "ViewController B" on a button action. I am trying to pass the value from this controller to  `messageBody` variable of `MessageSSCont.h` . The button action is like this :

```
    self.messageController = [[MessageSSCont alloc]init];
    self.messageController.messageBody = @"jfhjkhasfjhkwhfhdfjkjkfbhiehf";
    [self presentViewController:self.messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But unfortunately when the MFMessageComposeViewController is presented the value of `messageBody`is null. Where I am doing wrong in this scenario. Why my variable is not getting passed to the `MessageCont.h`class?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to subclass `MFMessageComposeViewController` ...   Take a look at the example in this article: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/

Answer (score 1):

OK - you have subclassed `MFMessageComposeViewController`, so you have its properties / methods available to your class.

You don't need these in your `.h` file:

```
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *messageBody;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *receivingNumber;
```

You can call your custom `MFMessageComposeViewController` like this:

```
self.messageController = [[MessageControllerKony alloc]init];

//self.messageController.messageBody = @"jfhjkhasfjhkwhfhdfjkjkfbhiehf";

[self.messageController setBody:@"jfhjkhasfjhkwhfhdfjkjkfbhiehf"];
[self.messageController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"13123123"]];

[self presentViewController:self.messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made my day. Thanks a lot